# Are there infinitely many emirps?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

An [emirp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirp) is a prime number such that when its decimal digits are reversed, one obtains a different prime number. Are there infinitely many ermips?

It is apparently open whether there are infinitely many 
[palindromic primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_prime) (a somewhat related but disjoint notion).

Comment: I think justice says the correct name should be **emirp** ...

Comment: fixed -- sorry.

Comment: from http://oeis.org/A178545: "It is conjectured but also unproved that there are infinitely many emirps (see A048054)."